# How to call subform before main form for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I need my application to run this sub form first before the main form appears.

Below is my code to do that:
Application.myapp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyApplicationData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MySubMain>true</MySubMain>
  <MainForm>MainForm</MainForm>
  <SingleInstance>false</SingleInstance>
  <ShutdownMode>0</ShutdownMode>
  <EnableVisualStyles>true</EnableVisualStyles>
  <AuthenticationMode>0</AuthenticationMode>
  <SaveMySettingsOnExit>true</SaveMySettingsOnExit>
</MyApplicationData>
```

Program.vb(where my subform method is)
Imports Licenseform

```
Module Program
    Public Sub Main()

        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        Application.Run(New Licenseform.Licenseform)

    End Sub
End Module
```

When i tried to build the application,i got the following error:
[image]

However if i disable the sub form by setting the application file

```
<mySubMain>false</MySubMain>
```

It builds successfully.
Any idea what is wrong and how should i troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to disable the Application Framework and write your own `Main` method.  Simply handle the `Startup` event of the application, which you can access by clicking the 'View Application Events' button on the 'Application' page of the project properties.  You can display a modal dialogue there the same way as you would anywhere else.  If you set `e.Cancel` to `True` then the app will exit without ever creating the startup form.

As an example, I just created a new WinForms project and added a second form.  On that form I added two `Buttons` and then added this code:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub okButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles okButton.Click
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub

    Private Sub cancelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cancelButton.Click
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
    End Sub

End Class
```

I then used the button in the project properties I referred to earlier and added this code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            Dim dialogue As New Form2

            e.Cancel = (dialogue.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

When I ran the project, `Form2` was displayed first, even though `Form1` was the startup form.  If I clicked the 'OK' button then `Form2` was dismissed and `Form1` opened normally.  If I clicked the 'Cancel' button, the application exited without displaying `Form1`.

Comment: I think you have misread my question.I have re edit my question.I have created a form to do checking of license using a third party API and this form will start up before the main form start ups.I trying to use subform to achieve that but failed.

Comment: There's no such thing as a subform in Windows Forms.  There's just forms.  If you want to display a form before the startup form is created then do as I said.  Don't create your own `Main` method and don't disable the Application Framework in the project properties.